# Extract Object values from one JSON and append to same Object in another JSON

Tags: json, powershell

I have 2 JSONs which are structurally similar, as below. I want to extract all key/values under "Jobs" Object from the 1st JSON and plug it into the 2nd JSON under the same "Jobs" Object. I have been able to extract and combine "Jobs" from both JSONs but I am unable to work out how to update the 2nd JSON inline to have the combined "Jobs" and retain the existing parent objects other than "Jobs". I have posted my PS Script so far. Any suggestions on how I can do this?

Note : The DBM* property name in the first line of the JSON will not always start with DBM.

**1st JSON**

```
{
  "DBM0003": {
  "Type":  "Folder",
  "ControlmServer": "vl-aus-dbaqa001",
  "ActiveRetentionPolicy": "CleanEndedOK",
  "SubApplication": "VSAUSUBAPP",
  "CreatedBy": "emuser",
  "Application": "VSAUAPP",
  "Jobs": [
    {
      "Type": "Job:Command",
      "SubApplication": "VSAUSUBAPP",
      "CreatedBy": "emuser",
      "Description": "Test Job",
      "RunAs": "ctmagent",
      "Application": "VSAUAPP",
      "Command": "hostname",
      "Name": "DBMAU001",
      "When": {
        "WeekDays": [
          "NONE"
        ],
        "MonthDays": [
          "ALL"
        ],
        "DaysRelation": "OR",
        "RuleBasedCalendars": {
          "Relationship": "AND",
          "Included": [
            "CAP_0001"
          ]
        }
      },
      "eventsToWaitFor": {
        "Type": "WaitForEvents",
        "Events": [
          {
            "Event": "CAPU003-TO-DBMAU001-273"
          }
        ]
      },
      "eventsToAdd": {
        "Type": "AddEvents",
        "Events": [
          {
            "Event": "DBMAU001-TO-DBMAU002-341"
          }
        ]
      },
      "eventsToDelete": {
        "Type": "DeleteEvents",
        "Events": [
          {
            "Event": "CAPU003-TO-DBMAU001-273"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "Type": "Job:Command",
      "SubApplication": "VSAUSUBAPP",
      "CreatedBy": "emuser",
      "Description": "Test Job",
      "RunAs": "ctmagent",
      "Application": "VSAUAPP",
      "Command": "cat $HOME/installed-versions.txt",
      "Name": "DBMAU002",
      "When": {
        "WeekDays": [
          "NONE"
        ],
        "MonthDays": [
          "ALL"
        ],
        "DaysRelation": "OR",
        "RuleBasedCalendars": {
          "Relationship": "AND",
          "Included": [
            "CAP_0001"
          ]
        }
      },
      "eventsToWaitFor": {
        "Type": "WaitForEvents",
        "Events": [
          {
            "Event": "DBMAU001-TO-DBMAU002-341"
          }
        ]
      },
      "eventsToAdd": {
        "Type": "AddEvents",
        "Events": [
          {
            "Event": "DBMAU002-TO-DBMAU003-341"
          }
        ]
      },
      "eventsToDelete": {
        "Type": "DeleteEvents",
        "Events": [
          {
            "Event": "DBMAU001-TO-DBMAU002-341"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "Type": "Job:Command",
      "SubApplication": "VSAUSUBAPP",
      "CreatedBy": "emuser",
      "Description": "Test Job",
      "RunAs": "ctmagent",
      "Application": "VSAUAPP",
      "Command": "cat $HOME/installed-versions.txt",
      "Name": "DBMAU003",
      "When": {
        "WeekDays": [
          "NONE"
        ],
        "MonthDays": [
          "ALL"
        ],
        "DaysRelation": "OR",
        "RuleBasedCalendars": {
          "Relationship": "AND",
          "Included": [
            "CAP_0001"
          ]
        }
      },
      "eventsToWaitFor": {
        "Type": "WaitForEvents",
        "Events": [
          {
            "Event": "DBMAU002-TO-DBMAU003-341"
          }
        ]
      },
      "eventsToDelete": {
        "Type": "DeleteEvents",
        "Events": [
          {
            "Event": "DBMAU002-TO-DBMAU003-341"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "When": {
    "RuleBasedCalendars": {
      "Included": [
        "CAP_0001"
      ],
      "CAP_0001": {
        "Type": "Calendar:RuleBased",
        "When": {
          "DaysRelation": "OR",
          "WeekDays": [
            "NONE"
          ],
          "MonthDays": [
            "ALL"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
  }
}
```

**2nd JSON**

```
{
  "DBM0002": {
  "Type":  "Folder",
  "ControlmServer": "vl-aus-dbaqa001",
  "ActiveRetentionPolicy": "CleanEndedOK",
  "SubApplication": "VSAUSUBAPP",
  "CreatedBy": "emuser",
  "Application": "VSAUAPP",
  "Jobs": [
    {
      "Type": "Job:Command",
      "SubApplication": "VSAUSUBAPP",
      "CreatedBy": "emuser",
      "Description": "Test Job",
      "RunAs": "ctmagent",
      "Application": "VSAUAPP",
      "Command": "hostname",
      "Name": "DBMAU004",
      "When": {
        "WeekDays": [
          "NONE"
        ],
        "MonthDays": [
          "ALL"
        ],
        "DaysRelation": "OR",
        "RuleBasedCalendars": {
          "Relationship": "AND",
          "Included": [
            "CAP_0001"
          ]
        }
      },
      "eventsToWaitFor": {
        "Type": "WaitForEvents",
        "Events": [
          {
            "Event": "CAPU003-TO-DBMAU004"
          }
        ]
      },
      "eventsToAdd": {
        "Type": "AddEvents",
        "Events": [
          {
            "Event": "DBMAU004-TO-DBMAU005"
          }
        ]
      },
      "eventsToDelete": {
        "Type": "DeleteEvents",
        "Events": [
          {
            "Event": "CAPU003-TO-DBMAU004"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "Type": "Job:Command",
      "SubApplication": "VSAUSUBAPP",
      "CreatedBy": "emuser",
      "Description": "Test Job",
      "RunAs": "ctmagent",
      "Application": "VSAUAPP",
      "Command": "hostname",
      "Name": "DBMAU004",
      "When": {
        "WeekDays": [
          "NONE"
        ],
        "MonthDays": [
          "ALL"
        ],
        "DaysRelation": "OR",
        "RuleBasedCalendars": {
          "Relationship": "AND",
          "Included": [
            "CAP_0001"
          ]
        }
      },
      "eventsToWaitFor": {
        "Type": "WaitForEvents",
        "Events": [
          {
            "Event": "CAPU003-TO-DBMAU004"
          }
        ]
      },
      "eventsToAdd": {
        "Type": "AddEvents",
        "Events": [
          {
            "Event": "DBMAU004-TO-DBMAU005"
          }
        ]
      },
      "eventsToDelete": {
        "Type": "DeleteEvents",
        "Events": [
          {
            "Event": "CAPU003-TO-DBMAU004"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "Type": "Job:Command",
      "SubApplication": "VSAUSUBAPP",
      "CreatedBy": "emuser",
      "Description": "Test Job",
      "RunAs": "ctmagent",
      "Application": "VSAUAPP",
      "Command": "cat $HOME/installed-versions.txt",
      "Name": "DBMAU005",
      "When": {
        "WeekDays": [
          "NONE"
        ],
        "MonthDays": [
          "ALL"
        ],
        "DaysRelation": "OR",
        "RuleBasedCalendars": {
          "Relationship": "AND",
          "Included": [
            "CAP_0001"
          ]
        }
      },
      "eventsToWaitFor": {
        "Type": "WaitForEvents",
        "Events": [
          {
            "Event": "DBMAU004-TO-DBMAU005"
          }
        ]
      },
      "eventsToAdd": {
        "Type": "AddEvents",
        "Events": [
          {
            "Event": "DBMAU005-TO-DBMAU006"
          }
        ]
      },
      "eventsToDelete": {
        "Type": "DeleteEvents",
        "Events": [
          {
            "Event": "DBMAU004-TO-DBMAU005"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "Type": "Job:Command",
      "SubApplication": "VSAUSUBAPP",
      "CreatedBy": "emuser",
      "Description": "Test Job",
      "RunAs": "ctmagent",
      "Application": "VSAUAPP",
      "Command": "cat $HOME/installed-versions.txt",
      "Name": "DBMAU006",
      "When": {
        "WeekDays": [
          "NONE"
        ],
        "MonthDays": [
          "ALL"
        ],
        "DaysRelation": "OR",
        "RuleBasedCalendars": {
          "Relationship": "AND",
          "Included": [
            "CAP_0001"
          ]
        }
      },
      "eventsToWaitFor": {
        "Type": "WaitForEvents",
        "Events": [
          {
            "Event": "DBMAU005-TO-DBMAU006"
          }
        ]
      },
      "eventsToDelete": {
        "Type": "DeleteEvents",
        "Events": [
          {
            "Event": "DBMAU005-TO-DBMAU006"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "When": {
    "RuleBasedCalendars": {
      "Included": [
        "CAP_0001"
      ],
      "CAP_0001": {
        "Type": "Calendar:RuleBased",
        "When": {
          "DaysRelation": "OR",
          "WeekDays": [
            "NONE"
          ],
          "MonthDays": [
            "ALL"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
  }
}
```

**PS Script**

```
$sourcejson = Get-Content 'DBM0002.json' | ConvertFrom-Json
$destjson = Get-Content 'DBM0003.json' | ConvertFrom-Json

$sourcefolder = $sourcejson.PsObject.Properties.Name
$sourcejobs = $sourcejson.$($sourcefolder).Jobs
$sourcejobsjson = $sourcejobs | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99
$sourcejobsnames = $sourcejson.$($sourcefolder).Jobs.Name
$sourcejobscount = $sourcejson.$($sourcefolder).Jobs.Name.Count

$destfolder = $destjson.PsObject.Properties.Name
$destjobs = $destjson.$($destfolder).Jobs
$destjobsjson = $destjobs | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99
$destjobsnames = $destjson.$($destfolder).Jobs.Name
$destjobscount = $destjson.$($destfolder).Jobs.Name.Count

$destjobs += $sourcejobs
$destjobs | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99 | Add-Content -Path Combined.json


$sourcejson = Get-Content 'DBM0002.json' | ConvertFrom-Json
$destjson = Get-Content 'DBM0003.json' | ConvertFrom-Json

$sourcefolder = @($sourcejson.PsObject.Properties)[0].Name
$sourcejobs = @($sourcejson.PSObject.Properties)[0].Value.Jobs
$sourcejobsnames = @($sourcejson.PSObject.Properties)[0].Value.Jobs.Name
$sourcejobscount = @($sourcejson.PSObject.Properties)[0].Value.Jobs.Name.Count

$destfolder = @($destjson.PsObject.Properties)[0].Name
$destjobs = @($destjson.PSObject.Properties)[0].Value.Jobs
$destjobsnames = @($destjson.PSObject.Properties)[0].Value.Jobs.Name
$destjobscount = @($destjson.PSObject.Properties)[0].Value.Jobs.Name.Count

# Option 1
$destjobs += $sourcejobs
# Option 2
@($destjson.PSObject.Properties)[0].Value.Jobs += @(@($sourcejson.PSObject.Properties)[0].Value.Jobs)
# Option 3
@($destjson.PSObject.Properties)[0].Value.Jobs += @($sourcejson.PSObject.Properties)[0].Value.Jobs
$destjson | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99 | Add-Content -Path Combined.json


Write-Host $sourcefolder","$sourcejobscount"," -NoNewline && Write-Host $sourcejobsnames -Separator ":"
Write-Host $destfolder","$destjobscount"," -NoNewline && Write-Host $destjobsnames -Separator ":"
```

Comment: Don't `ConvertTo-Json` __before merging them__. You could do `$json2.PSObject.Properties.Match('DBM*').Value.Jobs += @($json1.PSOBject.Properties.Match('DBM*').Value.Jobs)` then just `$json2 | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you're trying to do, then what you should do is merge the `Jobs` arrays **before** converting them back to Json. It's also assumed that you're trying to dynamically reference the property value using:

```
$sourcefolder = $sourcejson.PsObject.Properties.Name
$sourcejobs = $sourcejson.$($sourcefolder).Jobs
```

Perhaps this could be simplified using [`.Match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psmemberinfocollection-1.match?view=powershellsdk-7.4.0#system-management-automation-psmemberinfocollection-1-match(system-string)), considering the property name's start with `DBM` you could use the following wildcard pattern to get the value:

```
$sourcejobs = $sourcejson.PSObject.Properties.Match('DBM*').Value.Jobs
```

As for joining 2 arrays you can use [`+=`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_assignment_operators?view=powershell-7.4#the-assignment-by-addition-operator), using a simplified version of your Jsons for this demo:

```bash
$json1 = ConvertFrom-Json @'
{
  "DBM0003": {
    "Jobs": [
      {
        "Name": "Job1"
      }
    ]
  }
}
'@

$json2 = ConvertFrom-Json @'
{
  "DBM0004": {
    "Jobs": [
      {
        "Name": "Job2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
'@

$json2.PSObject.Properties.Match('DBM*').Value.Jobs +=
    @($json1.PSObject.Properties.Match('DBM*').Value.Jobs)
$json2 | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99
```

If not all Jsons have a property starting with `DBM` but **they all are a single object with 1 property**, what you can do is get the property value at index `0`:

```bash
@($json2.PSObject.Properties)[0].Value.Jobs +=
    @(@($json1.PSObject.Properties)[0].Value.Jobs)
$json2 | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99
```

Which results in the following Json:

```json
{
  "DBM0004": {
    "Jobs": [
      {
        "Name": "Job2"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Job1"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: property names will not always start with DBM*. So the Match may not work for me. Thanks. I have now sighted this in my question.

Comment: you could do `@($sourcejson.PSObject.Properties)[0].Value.Jobs` in that case @venky_au but that assumes the Json is a single outer object

Comment: Can you please edit your original answer with this new suggestion. Beyond the Jobs object the JSONs are going to have only 1 level of Object at the top and below and you can see this in my example JSONs. So Jobs is always going to be the middle part. Idea is that grab Jobs.Values alone from 1st JSON while we ignoring the outer info in 1st JSON and merging it in to the Jobs of 2nd JSON while retaining the outer object of the 2nd JSON.

Comment: Thanks I see it now. But how is this different from $destjobs += $sourcejobs which I am doing in my script already. See original post.

Comment: @venky_au I never saw the edited comment. your code is actually doing the same as my code in a different way, however, the issue with your code is that you're converting to json the `.Jobs` array: `$destjobs | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99` instead of converting the original Json with the `.Jobs` property updated: `$destjson | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99...`

Comment: @santisq Thanks. I have updated my PS Script. See edited original script above. I have couple of questions for you. Option 1 : $destjobs += $sourcejobs, my way doesn't work , only the destjobs array values are retained Option 2 : This is your option which works perfectly fine. Option 3 : modified version of your option where I am using array sub-expression operator @ only once in $sourcejson.PSObject.Properties)[0].Value.Jobs as compared to twice in your answer and this also works fine. Questions : Any feedback on why Option 1 is not working Difference between Option 2 & 3